# Dropdown border issue in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, select, border

[image]

Firefox is cutting off the border of dropdown select or making them look hideous in some cases(making left border grey and right border black).

Is there a fix for this in CSS?

I am using Bootstrap, UniformJS(removing this didn't change anything).

Comment: I'm still getting this issue over two years later... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a firefox bug. You can check it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068).

Best way would be to give width 99.99% instead of 100% in your css.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer by Rhythm Patel, add the following to your CSS or  element.

```
select {
    width: 99% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. It is a bug From Firefox web browser.

Set Width Of Your Select Box In CSS

```
select {
 width: 99% !important;
}
```

or add class to select tag and set width